# BPM - byte array - not expected

Tags: java, arrays, jbpm, business-process-management

I've got a problem when trying to compress a .xls file into a zip file in a BPM platform (BEA Aqualogic BPM - Studio).
This is my code so far:

```
try {
FileOutputStream fos = FileOutputStream(arg1 : "/home/and/Reportes/zipTest.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = ZipOutputStream(arg1 : fos);

logMessage("MAS - zippeo en: " + url);

Java.Io.File file = Java.File(arg1 : url);
FileInputStream fis = FileInputStream(arg1 : file);
ZipEntry entry = ZipEntry(arg1 : url);
zos.putNextEntry(arg1 : entry);

int buff = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[buff];

int length;
//int buffer = 1024;

while((length = fis.read(buffer,0,1024)) >= 0){
    zos.write(arg1 : buffer, arg2 : 0, arg3 : length);
}
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
logMessage("MAS - FNFE: " + e.stackTrace);
}
catch (IOException e) {
logMessage("MAS - IOE: " + e.stackTrace);
}
```

What I'm getting, is a compiling error:

```
''byte'' not expected
```

And those are simple quotation marks btw (as in ' ')

Any idea as to what could it be or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Also, I'm getting another error:

```
Argument not valid for 'arg1'. Type 'byte array' not compatible with 'Binary'
```

in the "fis.read" and"zos.write"

Comment: Could you post syntactically-valid code please?

Comment: What do you mean by "What I'm getting"? Is this an exception? A compile-time error? The contents of the file? Please be more specific in your question (and ideally format your code, too...)

Comment: What do you expect `zos.write(arg1 : buffer, arg2 : 0, arg3 : length)` to mean? Why have you got `arg1 : `, `arg2 : ` and `arg3 :`? It sounds like you need to read up on the basics of Java, to be honest...

Comment: it's a compiling error
and 'arg1: ', etc are just the way the platform takes the functions (arguments)